# Сссылка для перехода на страницу товара

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, controller

Хочу сделать переход на страницу товара
Вот код контроллера

```
@GetMapping(value = "/case")
public String shopPage(Model model, @RequestParam("id") Long id, Principal principal) {
    try {
        String username = principal.getName();
        if (username != null) {
            User user = userService.findByLogin(username);
            if (!user.isFieldsNotNull()) {
                return "redirect:/" + username;
            }
            model.addAttribute("sign", "выйти");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute("sign", "войти");
    }
    ShopCaseDto shop = shopMapper.toShopCaseDto(shopService.findById(id));
    List<ShopCaseItemDto> shopItems = shop.getItems();
    ShopCaseItemDto ratingItem = shopService.getTheMostRatingItem(shop.getItems());
    List<ImageDto> images = ratingItem.getImages();
    ImageDto logo = shop.getLogo();

    model.addAttribute("shop", shop);
    model.addAttribute("images", shopService
            .convertListImages(images));
    model.addAttribute("shopItems", shopItems);
    model.addAttribute("logo", shopService.convertImage(logo));
    model.addAttribute("ratingItem", ratingItem);

    return "shop_page";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/item")
public String itemPage(Model model, @RequestParam("shop") Long shopId, @RequestParam("item") Long itemId, Principal principal) {
    try {
        String username = principal.getName();
        if (username != null) {
            User user = userService.findByLogin(username);
            if (!user.isFieldsNotNull()) {
                return "redirect:/" + username;
            }
            model.addAttribute("sign", "выйти");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute("sign", "войти");
    }
    Item item = shopService.getItemById(shopService.findById(shopId).getItems(), itemId);


    List<ImageDto> images = imageMapper.toListImageDto(item.getImages());

    model.addAttribute("item", itemMapper.itemToItemDTO(item));
    model.addAttribute("image", shopService.convertListImages(images));
    return "shop_item_page";
}
```

Вот код карточки, где я хочу сделать кнопку с переходом на страницу

```
<div class="row" th:fragment="list" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<div th:each="shop_item,stat: ${shopItems}" class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card mb-3">

        <div class="card-body">

            <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${shop_item.name}">Product Name</h5>
            <p class="card-text" th:text="${shop_item.description}">Material</p>
            <p class="card-text" th:text="${shop_item.rating}">Price</p>
            <a th:href="@{/shop/{id}/item/{itemid} (id=${shop.id} ,itemid=${shop_item.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Открыть</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

В итоге я открываю эту ссылку

```
http://localhost:8888/shop/2/item/3
```

Высвечивает такую ошибку

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Nov 22 20:58:24 MSK 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Объясните пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно

Comment: Все правильно Спринг пишет. Приведите полностью код контроллера

Comment: Добавил ответ...

Comment: Если ответ верный, то Вы можете отметить его как правильный. См. справку: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Spring выдает ошибку, т.к. вы ссылаетесь и пытаете открыть страницу, которая не обрабатывается ни одним из методов, которые вы привели в данном вопросе.
Почему так случилось и что с этим делать разберемся ниже.

## @RequestParam

@RequestParam - это аннотация, которая перехватывает параметр запроса.
Именно **ПАРАМЕТР ЗАПРОСА** и ничто иное.
Это то, что передается после вопросительного знака в строке запроса.

```
http://localhost:8888/home?param1=test&param2=value
```

В данном случае мы бы могли перехватить эти данные с помощью следующих аннотаций и параметров

```
@RequestParam("param1") String firstParameter, @RequestParam("param2") String secondParameter
```

И это значит, что это не то что нам нужно, потому что с помощью данных аннотаций мы не можем извлечь данные из пути... (*того что указано до знака вопроса*)
Для таких вещей используются **переменные пути** и мы о них поговорим чуть позже.

## @GetMapping

Аннотация @GetMapping позволяет связать запросы, соответствующие указанному шаблону, с методом, который будет их обрабатывать.

В данном случае аннотация `@GetMapping(value = "/item")` позволяет нам обрабатывать запросы вида `http://localhost:8888/item` или в лучшем случае `http://localhost:8888/shop/item` (*при условии, что вы еще указали mapping над самим контроллером*)

И это опять не то, что нам нужно.

Исходя из всех исходных, запрос, который обрабатывает метод `itemPage()` вашего контроллера должен был бы выглядеть вот так:

```
http://localhost:8888/item?shop=123&item=456
```

или

```
http://localhost:8888/shop/item?shop=123&item=456
```

(при условии проставленной аннотации с путем над контроллером)

Вы же ожидаете:

```
http://localhost:8888/shop/123/item/456
```

**Теперь давайте разберемся как этого достигнуть**

## @PathVariable

Как я уже упоминал, Вам нужно было использовать переменные пути.
Аннотация `@PathVariable` позволяет связать параметр метода контроллера с частью шаблона, которому должен удовлетворять запрос.

Для этого в шаблоне пути используются плейсхолдеры, ограниченные справа и слева фигурными скобками

**Например**:

```
@GetMapping(value="/schools/{school}/courses/{course}/materials")
```

В аннотации указаны два плейсхолдера `{school}` и `{course}`, которые мы впоследствии можем перехватить с помощью аннотаций, следующим образом:

```
@PathVariable("school") Long schoolId, @PathVariable("course") Long courseId,
```

**В вашем случае эта пара будет выглядеть следующим образом**:
Шаблон:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/shop/{shop}/item/{item}")
```

или

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{shop}/item/{item}")
```

если над контроллером указан шаблон ("/shop")
и параметры:

```
@PathVariable("shop") Long shopId, @PathVariable("item") Long itemId,
```

## Итог:

```java
// метод shopPage() в данном листинге не указываю, т.к. он без изменений

// далее
@GetMapping(value = "/shop/{shop}/item/{item}")
public String itemPage(Model model, @PathVariable("shop") Long shopId, @PathVariable("item") Long itemId, Principal principal) {
    try {
        String username = principal.getName();
        if (username != null) {
            User user = userService.findByLogin(username);
            if (!user.isFieldsNotNull()) {
                return "redirect:/" + username;
            }
            model.addAttribute("sign", "выйти");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute("sign", "войти");
    }
    Item item = shopService.getItemById(shopService.findById(shopId).getItems(), itemId);

    List<ImageDto> images = imageMapper.toListImageDto(item.getImages());

    model.addAttribute("item", itemMapper.itemToItemDTO(item));
    model.addAttribute("image", shopService.convertListImages(images));
    return "shop_item_page";
}
```